# Looping an object with an string array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rather new to jQuery and I don't understand why this loop doesn't display 
the object properties.

I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
var shop_array = ["title","price","img","text"];
var submit = $(".add").find(":submit");
submit.on("click",function(e){
    var elements = $(".add").children(':input');
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        if($(elements[i]).val()!==""){
            var object = '\"'+shop_array[i]+'\"';
            console.log(shopcart.shop_values[object])//dosen't display shop_value;
            console.log(object);
        }
    }
});
var shopcart= {
    shop_values :{
        "title":"a",
        "price":"b",
        "img":"img",
        "text":"text"
    },
    add: function(){

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all `object` is a really bad variable name, and will lead to confusion. Secondly, you're appending leading and trailing slashes to the value, where none of the values in the `shop_values` object have slashes, so they're never going to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `"` you put around the variable you want to use to access the object properties, they should not be there as they are not in the property names

```
var object = '\"'+shop_array[i]+'\"';
console.log(shopcart.shop_values[object])//dosen't display shop_value;
```

should just be

```
console.log(shopcart.shop_values[shop_array[i]])//dosen't display shop_value;
```

For your current code to have worked the `shopcart` would need to be defined as

```
var shopcart= {
    shop_values :{
        "\"title\"":"a",
        "\"price\"":"b",
        "\"img\"":"img",
        "\"text\"":"text"
    },
    add: function(){

    }
}
```

which would look just awful.